# Pointer expressions in C

Tags: c

What is the difference between the following pointer expressions

```
*ptr++
```

---

```
++*ptr
```

---

```
(*ptr)++
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? If it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: No, its not a homework problem. I read in a book that they are different but it does not say how. So i asked !!

Comment: What does the book say? Did you read about operator precedence?

Comment: Its not a theory book. Its a MCQ book and in the answer it says that they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one will is equivalent to `*(ptr++)` which will will return a temporary pointer with it's current value and then increment ptr.

The second one will increment the value pointed to by `ptr` (assuming it is a type with `++` defined) and return the incremented value

The third one will return the current value pointed to by `ptr` and then increment `ptr`

Ex.

```
int a = 0;
int * ptr = &a;
int b = *ptr++;
```

a = 0, b = 0, but `ptr` will point to nonsense.

```
int a = 0;
int * ptr = &a;
int b = ++*ptr;
```

a = 1, b = 1

```
int a = 0;
int * ptr = &a;
int b = (*ptr)++;
```

a = 1, b = 0

Comment: I think that Daniel Fisher's answer is better than mine.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11105148/380231

Answer (score 3):

The first, `*ptr++;`, increments the pointer and evaluates to the value the pointer pointed to before the increment.

The second, `++*ptr;`, dereferences the pointer and increments the pointed to value, its value is the incremented value.

The third, `(*ptr)++`, dereferences the pointer and increments the pointed-to value, its value is the pointed-to value before the increment.

Consider e.g. `int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` and `ptr = &arr[1];`.

- After `int val = *ptr++;`, the pointer `ptr` points to `arr[2]` and `val` is 2.
- After `int val = ++*ptr;`, the pointer `ptr` still points to `arr[1]`, `arr[1]` is incremented, so now its value is 3, and so is `val`.
- After `int val = (*ptr)++;`, the pointer still points to `arr[1]`, `arr[1]` is incremented, so its value is now 3, but `val` has the old value of `arr[1]`, 2.